# How do I find what is causing ORA-00054?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-00054

For past some time I have noticed that we get `ORA-00054` error while trying to issue `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`, during large number of concurrent updates to the db. This our development system and we really do not have any other user, or at least that is what we believe.

We have been through the logs of our application and it seems everything is in order; no threads are trying to update the same row.

How can I configure Oracle db to generate a log on which would let me know the user id which holds the lock when this error occurred?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4515126525609

Comment: When you say "large number of concurrent updates" could you please explain in more detail what your application is doing?

Comment: related question I'd asked on [dba.se] [Tracing, debugging and fixing Row Lock Contentions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1726/120)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from here: [ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075738/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified)

You can also look up the sql,username,machine,port information and get to the actual process which holds the connection

```
SELECT O.OBJECT_NAME, S.SID, S.SERIAL#, P.SPID, S.PROGRAM,S.USERNAME,
S.MACHINE,S.PORT , S.LOGON_TIME,SQ.SQL_FULLTEXT 
FROM V$LOCKED_OBJECT L, DBA_OBJECTS O, V$SESSION S, 
V$PROCESS P, V$SQL SQ 
WHERE L.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID 
AND L.SESSION_ID = S.SID AND S.PADDR = P.ADDR 
AND S.SQL_ADDRESS = SQ.ADDRESS;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, in my case the root cause was ITL contention. We had smaller rows, so many of them gets packed into a single block. Header did not reserve enough space for ITL entries when all the the rows were locked simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the NOWAIT, and monitor DBA_BLOCKERS/DBA_WAITERS.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option for me, since the code which does that is deep inside the framework we use. Also we don't have the source code.

Comment: You may be able to modify the SQL statements with DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE: http://dioncho.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/optimizing-unoptimizeable-sql-dbms_advanced_rewrite/

Comment: @jonearles It would be interesting to know if that's possible on a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT -- I'm pretty sure you couldn't override the NOWAIT as that's not part of the sub-select statement that would be specified in dbms_advanced_rewrite.

Comment: @David You're right, it doesn't work with `FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`.  I get the error `ORA-30389: the source statement is not compatible with the destination statement`.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use

```
select * from v$locked_object
```

for getting the lock information

Since it is development environment you can try the approach provided in the below link

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=324530

A more comprehensive Approach is provided using v$lock at the below link

http://www.orafaq.com/node/854