# SQL Developer - Delete 90,000 rows

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00054

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075738/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified)

I have a table in sql dev that I want to clear all data from. There are about 90,000+ rows. I just want to delete data and not the table.

Everything I've tried hasn't worked ie DELETE *, TRUNCATE. I keep running into

> ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

error

Comment: how come truncate didn't work ? what error did you get ?

Comment: what do you mean it hasn't worked? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What error do you get? Or what is the outcome?

Comment: what error did you get? Anyways, ff it's just a one-time-thing I recommend ignoring the errors, dropping the table and creating a new table afterwards

Comment: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

Comment: make sure records you are deleting have not child records in another table

Comment: you probaly have transaction pending in another window or applicattion, that's why you are getting "resource busy", another transaction hasn't finished yet and has whole table or some records locked

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your truncate or delete syntax is incorrect? What is the error message you see when running one of the following:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]
```

or

```
DELETE FROM [TableName]
```

See [Delete](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8005.htm) and [Truncate](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm)

**Update for ORA-00054**

This error probably means your table is locked by a query in another session. See the following SO question and [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4842778/444610) relating to this error number.

[ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842765/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified-or-timeout-expired#4842778)

FYI - error numbers like that don't usually mean much to a human, but they can be gold when [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ORA-00054) for specifics in a search engine or a site like SO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with SQL Developer, but if you have transactions enabled make sure to COMMIT the transaction if you want the effects of the command(s) you issue to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table_name
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this post will help you alot to solve the problem. As from what I see you are dealing with an oracle error:

http://www.bluegecko.net/oracle/ora-00054-resource-busy-and-acquire-with-nowait-specified/

It also tell how to circumvent your particular lock.